# How many squares of light does a mundane lantern light up in 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, vision-and-light

I'm running a roll20 4th edition game and, having recently purchased dynamic lighting and started designing the first dungeon that the players will explore, run almost immediately into a question - that is, lighting. How much light does a regular, mundane, nonmagical lantern emit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mundane lantern will shed bright light in a 10 square radius, as per page 167 of the Rules Compendium:

> Source: Lantern
>
> Brightness: Bright
>
> Radius: 10 squares
>
> Duration: 8 hours per pint of oil